# Batch File - Tasklist - FindStr

Tags: batch-file, tasklist

In my batch file, I'm trying to kill a task with its name, if it's running.
To do so, I use the following commands

```
Tasklist | findstr "abc.exe"
IF %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 Taskkill /F /IM "abc.exe"
```

The problem is, there may be more than one isntance of "abc.exe" running.
Both are stored in two different locations (say, C:\A\abc.exe, C:\B\abc.exe).

Is there a way to kill only C:\A\abc.exe?

Answer (score -2):

This is just a thought...but try killing the task using its 'pid' instead of the application name

taskkill -f -pid xxxx

where xxxx is the numeric pid

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. yeah, we can use PID; but, everytime I run this application, it'll have different PID. Right? That is the reason, I'm not able to use PID. Could you please suggest me some other way?

Comment: the problem here is how to 'grep' the task list in Windows